# sending notification from Isolated

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to send notifications from background process by Isolated when app is closed 
but I have the error
How can I do that without use scheduled notification because I need to execute a specific code
Note:
If this code will not run please advice me in another way

```dart
import [...]
void main() {..}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  void callerCreateIsolate() async {
    await Isolate.spawn(
      echo,
      '',
    );
  }


  static void echo(String s)  {
    print('isolate');
   showNotification();
  }

  static Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    debugPrint("payload : $payload");
    showDialog(
      builder: (_) =>
      new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Notification'),
        content: new Text('$payload'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Flutter Local Notification'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: callerCreateIsolate,
                child: new Text(
                  'Isolate',
                  style: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  static showNotification() async {
    print('showNotification');
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var _android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('bigbenicon');
    var _iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(_android, _iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
      priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max,

    );
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, 'title', 'body', platform,
        payload: 'closed');
  }

}
```

> D/ViewRootImpl@dbbebd7MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dbbebd7MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1 I/flutter (
>   1863): isolate I/flutter ( 1863): showNotification E/flutter ( 1863):
>   [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(805)] Unhandled exception:
>   E/flutter ( 1863): error: native function 'Window_sendPlatformMessage'
>   (4 arguments) cannot be found E/flutter ( 1863): #0
>   Window.sendPlatformMessage (dart:ui/window.dart:1088:9) E/flutter (
>   1863): #1 _DefaultBinaryMessenger._sendPlatformMessage
>   (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:85:15) E/flutter (
>   1863): #2 _DefaultBinaryMessenger.send
>   (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:129:12) E/flutter
>   ( 1863): #3 MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:309:51) E/flutter
>   ( 1863):  E/flutter ( 1863): #4
>   FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize
>   (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications.dart:103:24)
>   E/flutter ( 1863):  E/flutter ( 1863): #5 _MyAppState.showNotification
>   (package:big_ben/main.dart:74:37) E/flutter ( 1863):  E/flutter (
>   1863): #6 _MyAppState.echo (package:big_ben/main.dart:29:4) E/flutter
>   ( 1863): #7 _startIsolate.
>   (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:304:17) E/flutter ( 1863): #8
>   _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)